# Why the run results as last line is "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: c++

The head file name is `Stack.h` as below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Stack
{
    struct Link
    {
        void* data;
        Link* next;
        Link(void* dat, Link* head);
        ~Link();
    } *head;

public:
    void push(void * dat);
    void* pop();
    void* peek();
    Stack();
    ~Stack();
};

Stack::Link::Link(void* dat, Link* head)
{
    data = dat;
    next = head;
}

Stack::Link::~Link() { }

void Stack::push(void* dat)
{
    head = new Link(dat, head);
}

Stack::Stack()
{
    head = 0;
}

void* Stack::pop()
{
    Link* old = head;
    void* result = head->data;
    head = head->next;
    delete old;
    return result;
}

void* Stack::peek()
{
    if (head == 0) return 0;
    return head->data;
}

Stack::~Stack()
{
    if (head != 0) cout << "Stack is not empty" << endl;
}

// this is cpp file name as StackTest.cpp
#include "Stack.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Stack stack;
    ifstream in("Stash.h");
    string line;
    while (getline(in, line))
    {
        stack.push(new string(line));
    }
    string* str;
    while (str = (string*)stack.pop())
    {
        cout << *str << endl;
        delete str;
    }
}
```

The run result last line as below:

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

compile command is

```
g++ Stash.h StashTest.cpp -o StashTest
```

in Ubuntu 12.04

Why the run result as last line is the `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`?

Comment: Go through the core file with your debugger to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are not checking if stack is empty in pop, so it crashes trying to get head->data when head is nullptr